# react hook forms is showing me incorrect (0) characters entered in text field and then correct field length on second click of submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, char, react-hook-form

I am using getValues with react-hook-form and then trying to render the length of the characters of the text field in an error message when user goes over the limit. I am seeing 0/1046 characters when i click submit the first time then the second time I see the correct number.

```html
const titleValue = getValues('title')
const descriptionValue = getValues('description')
  
   <TextField
                name='title'
                defaultValue=''
                label='Title*'
                control={control}
                css={{}}
                help={
                  errors.title?.type === 'required' || errors.title?.type === 'maxLength'
                    ? errors.title.message
                    : undefined
                }
                aria-label='title'
                rules={{
                  required: { value: true, message: 'Required' },
                  maxLength: {
                    value: 1024,
                    message: `${titleValue?.length || 0}/1024 maximum character length exceeded`,
                  },
                }}
              />
```

[image]

Comment: We're rather unable to help without actually seeing your code - we can't say if you're using `getValues` correctly and if not, what you're doing wrong.

Comment: added the code thanks

Answer (score 1):

react-hook-form provided an answer https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7668

````
  validate: (value) => {
    if (value.length >= 10) {
      // this will give you the correct value for your error message
      return `Please, enter a title with less than 10 characters (${value.length}/10)`;
    }
  }
}}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [useForm - getValues](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/getvalues/)

> An optimized helper for reading form values. The difference between
> watch and getValues is that getValues will not trigger re-renders or
> subscribe to input changes.

Where as [useForm - watch](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) seems to fit your needs more.

> This will watch specified inputs and return their values. It is useful
> for determining what to render.

```
const titleValue = watch('title')
```

Comment: ok i switched to watch but when i copy and paste into one field it shows correctly then copy and paste large text into description field it shows 0/4096 still is this a bug with react hook forms

Comment: If you could provide a way to reproduce the code via codesandbox for example I could look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/7668